# if include three statments ruby or compare arrays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My code lists all documents in a folder:

```
arr = [] 
file = Dir.entries('C:\Sites\what\upload').reject{|entry| entry == "." || entry == ".."}
file.each do |f|
a = File.read('C:\Sites\what\upload' + '/' + f) + f
```

and searches for files whose `patient.name`, `patient.vorname`, and `patient.birthday` are present. If so, the program assigns this document to the patient:

```
@patients.each do |patient|
if a.include?(patient.name) || a.include?(patient.vorname) || a.include?(patient.birthday)
```

My program somehow assigns documents to users that have nothing to do with the documents or better said, are not mentioned in the text. I think the problem is that my if statement is wrong.

Would it be better if I split the text before and compare the new array with `[patient.name, patient.vorname, patient.birtday]`?

```
arr << patient.id
first = Patient.find_by_id(patient.id)
second = first.images.create(:url => 'C:\Sites\what\upload' + f) 
end
end
end
```

Comment: If you need to check all three conditions and only then assign the document, you should be using `&&`, not `||`

Comment: Did you want to link the document to the patient if it contained their name *OR* their vorname *OR* their date of birth. Or should these *OR* be *AND*. If they should be and change your code to use && not ||

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below:

```
if [patient.name,patient.vorname,patient.birthday].all? {|i| a.include? i }
```

Comment: no, IT has to include all three statements! Thanks

Comment: @EmSta Then use `all?` instead of `any?`.